# Is there something like Diaspora written in PHP?

Tags: php, social-networks

I am looking for an open source social networking platform. [Diaspora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_network) is perfect, except it is not written in PHP. Is there a project like Diaspora written in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/index.php) fits that description. From their [about page](http://www.elgg.org/about.php):

> Elgg is an award-winning open source social networking engine that provides a robust framework on which to build all kinds of social environments, from a campus wide social network for your university, school or college or an internal collaborative platform for your organization through to a brand-building communications tool for your company and its clients.

Comment: @bingjie2680 You're welcome.